# How to fix image texture distortion

Tags: texturing, uv, edit-mode, faces, uv-image-editor

I have a wall that I need to put bricks on, but there's distortion around the windows... How can I remove the distortion in the UV Editor?

[image: Face that needs bricks positioned right]

Comment: I would just view it on an axis and UV -> Project From View -- the only difficulty with this method is keeping your selections straight while working

Comment: @AllenSimpson I wish you'd answered in an actual answer, because I would've accepted it as the answer... Thanks for recommending that, it worked :)

Answer (score 2):

Is it just that  the geometry has changed without a corresponding change in UV?

[image]

.. which would mean you just have to re-map, whichever way suits your workflow best.

Comment: Not sure if this answers your question, but I first cut the shapes and extruded them to make the windows, before I mapped the texture and applied it... Not sure how to fix this...

Comment: Hi, @prestonferry .. OK, if you edit your original post to include a share on  https://blend-exchange.com/ , then folks could have a look for you.

Comment: Allen Simpson answered it, I appreciate your attempt in helping :)

Comment: @prestonferry no problem, that's what we're here for :)